# DI Error when i add parameter in constructor SignalR

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, signalr

When i use parameter in constructor to do DI, i receive a message:
Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error.'.

This line:

```
        public Chat(MessagesRepository repository)
```

```
public class Chat : Hub
    {
        public static List<MessageModel> Messages;
        private readonly MessagesRepository _repository;

        public Chat(MessagesRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;

            if (Messages == null)
                Messages = new List<MessageModel>();
        }
```

Tks

I already try add AddScoped, AddTransient, AddSingleton, but not help me.

Comment: Can you show code where you register MessageRepository? You register it without interface? as standalone class? Dont you have IMessageRepository somewhere?